# Error creating bean with name and Application run failed. Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, compiler-errors

Please help me to fix this problem.
[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHFRH.png)

[screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6pkn.png)

here not full stack:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1290)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 33 common frames
>   omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory
>   method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 47 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/jpa/HibernatePersistenceProvider    at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:82)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.createJpaVendorAdapter(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:125)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:106)
>   ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]   ... 48 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 65 common frames omitted
>
> Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50084',
>   transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>code</groupId>
    <artifactId>tradehelper</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tradehelper</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.1.25</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>13</source>
                    <target>13</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins> 
    </build>

</project>
```

I'm so sorry, if it will be difficult to read. Please, ask me, if it needs more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error is that one:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider

You need to include a missing module

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I think this is the missing one.

Also remove this line:

```
<scope>compile>/scope>
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can just remove all hibernate related dependencies.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Hibernate gets pulled in by the spring data-jpa dependency automatically so no need to pull it in manually.

you can read about it here.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate